# Magento Captcha Issues in 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, captcha

I am new to magento. I have installed captcha extensions as [fontis](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fontis-recaptcha.html), [contacts form captcha](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/contacts-form-captcha-6079.html). Its is working local, but not in online.

In Contacts Form Captcha, whatever captcha text i type, it shows incorrect captcha.

In Fontis, this is the error message.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Fontis_Recaptcha_Helper_Data' not found in /public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546
```

Can any one please help me?

Comment: your compilation is on?

Answer (score 0):

Check if compilation is enabled under **admin > system > tools > compilation**.  If yes then disable it & check if captcha works for you. If yes then re run the compilation process & clear cache from "var/cache" folder

Answer (score 0):

Please check that there is file "Data.php" under app/code/community/Fontis/Recaptcha/Helper folder and it contains:

class Fontis_Recaptcha_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract

Also check that app/code/community/Fontis/Recaptcha/etc/config.xml contains:

```
<helpers>
<recaptcha>
<class>Fontis_Recaptcha_Helper</class>
</recaptcha>
</helpers>
```

After rechecking, check that compilation is disabled under admin > system > tools > compilation.

Now flush magento cache and check again.

Let me know if you find any difficulty.

Comment: Yes, i checked. still it is not working.. Is there any possibility?

Comment: you have mentioned in your question that you have installed another module for captcha [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/contacts-form-captcha-6079.html)

try disabling it from app/etc/modules

refresh cache and then check again.

Comment: I tried that too.. But still it is not working. Will that be version problem? i am using 1.7.0.2 and the extension compatible to 1.7